# can String.prototype.split() differentiate between two instances of a character

Tags: javascript, csv, split

I am working with rather large csv files (not mine, I cannot change the formatting of the files).
My script reads the files into a string, and then turns it into array by using .split() method first to split the rows using "\n".
The delimitator for the rows is the comma (",").
The problem is that the csv file is written to include the commas inside some of the values like so:

```
Type,Class,Result\n
AA,SG26,27%\n
AC,DC747,17%\n
"FF,RF",R$%,89%\n
HE,RT,56%\n
```

My function treats them as separate values, since it depends on split() with the delimitator of "," so it splits all the values like csv[2][Type] in this example into two.

I have tried using the replace function before splitting the string like so:

```
String.prototype.processCSV = function(delimiter = ","){
  var str;
  if(this.includes('"'){
    str = this.replace(/"\s,\s"/g, "");
  }
//rest of the function
}
```

But I do not see any results of doing that.

Is there any way to differentiate between the commas in the values and the separating commas, or any better way to read csv into arrays (please note that the array is then mapped so I can access the values by keys)?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I should add that the project is on a static page that loads the csv files into strings first with ajax xmlhttpresponse, not in the node, due to project requirements I cannot establish a node backend.

Comment: Use a csv parser. Your input csv file appears to be proper csv files so a real csv parser should work. As you have discovered csv is not just simply splitting on commas - it is a proper file format like XML or JSON. There are lots of csv parsers on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=csv

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I assume they work for the script as well (there is no real backend for this project, the page is static, it just processes data based on several csv files it fetches from the server), so instead of importing in the module I will need to use the script with src.

Comment: Look at my answer below. I demonstrated how to do it with Papaparse which is browser based (though later they added support for node.js) and very feature rich. Just add a link to the minified version in a `<script>` tag and off you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real way to "distinguish commas at different positions" is to parse the string, and process the characters between " differently.

```
  const input = `"1,1","2,2"`;
  
  let pos = 0;
  while (pos < input.length) {
     switch (input[pos]) {
        case `,`:
          // handle comma
          break;
        case `\n`:
          // handle newline
          break;
        case `"`:
          const end = input.indexOf(`"`, pos + 1);
          // handle string
          // skip processing the string
          pos = end;
          break;
     }
     pos += 1;
 }
```

But instead of writing your own parser (which is a fun exercise though) it is probably a good idea to use an existing implementation instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, yes I will probably will need to. But I will use your idea as a reference for an experiment later on.

Comment: You turned out right after all, since I am dealing with a specific case my parser which is based on your answer works much faster because it is optimized for the tables I need. I originally used Papa.parse as slebetman suggested and it worked great, the problem was with compatibility, sometimes it returned an error, and I had no idea why (because I didn't build it). I have completed part of my task thanks to slebetman and you suggesting using a parser, but have run into problems, so I just completed my parser which gives me no unexpected errors.

Comment: I guess, I should always make the solution from scratch when I can, as it will work much more specifically for the task at hand than the readily made ones that have to optimize for general use.

Comment: @aibarmanas yeah, that's the balance you usually need to find when reusing existing code. It sounds like you made some reasonable choices.

Answer (score 2):

Don't just split on `,`. That's not the correct way to handle CSV files. Use a real CSV parser.

There are lots of CSV parsers on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=csv). Here's an example using Papaparse ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/papaparse) or [official home page](https://www.papaparse.com/)):

```
var results = Papa.parse(csv, {
    header: true
});

console.log(results[0].Type);    // prints AA
console.log(results[0].Class);   // prints SG26
console.log(results[0].Result);  // prints 27%
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I assume they work for the script as well (there is no real backend for this project, the page is static, it just processes data based on several csv files it fetches from the server), so instead of importing in the module I will need to use the script with src.